# How to change the way Elements are added in a Unity Grid Layout Group?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

When I add an Element, for instance an image, to my Grid Layout Group, but the row is already full, a new row gets created. But the Grid is extended in the wrong direction; upwards but I want it to be extended downwards. I've tried changing about all settings which were available, but nothing changed on my problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: try to play with the pivot of the rect transform as well as the child alignment property in the grid layout component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the Start Corner setting does. Change it to change the way elements are added.